# CakePHP 3.7.5 app broken after composer update

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I decided to run "composer update" command another time to get the app back up to date but now it's completely broken as it can't find a certain class anymore.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Application' not found in C:\wamp64\www\HW2019\webroot\index.php on line 37

Error: Class 'App\Application' not found in C:\wamp64\www\HW2019\webroot\index.php on line 37

All files in the vendor folder have been properly uploaded, so yes also all the composer autoload class mappings ...

I really have no clue what I should do now

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `...\HW2019\src\Application.php` exist? Does it contain the `Application` class, in the `App` namespace?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;

// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));

Comment: This is in your `src\Application.php`? That's not right at all. This code should be in your `webroot\index.php`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Sir the Application.php is there

Comment: And does it contain the `Application` class, in the `App` namespace?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  namespace App;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Exception\MissingPluginException;
use Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\BaseApplication;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware;

/**
 * Application setup class.
 *
 * This defines the bootstrapping logic and middleware layers you
 * want to use in your application.
 */
class Application extends BaseApplication

Comment: That does look right. Seems like an autoloading issue is the most likely culprit. Rerun `composer dumpautoload` just to see if that fixes it?

Comment: @GregSchmidt

c:\wamp64\www\HW2019>composer dumpautoload
Generated autoload files containing 542 classes

Comment: And still getting the error after that?

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes sir still showing the same error

Comment: I guess you could poke around in the autoload files themselves to see if you can find the `App` namespace, and where it thinks it should be loaded from?